# Phpinfo shows the wrong php handler info

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, suphp

I set the php handler as **`suphp`** in cPanel WHM

When i execute **`/usr/local/cpanel/bin/rebuild_phpconf --current`** it shows php handler as **`suphp`**

But when i check phpinfo it shows **`FPM/FastCGI`**

Which one is the right info?

Comment: `phpinfo` from cli or webserver?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, both are right information:

- suPHP is your PHP Handler for CLI PHP (PHP executed through your terminal)
- FPM is your PHP Handler for your "web" PHP processes (the PHP that handles HTTP request from your webserver).

Comment: I am too facing the same problem, but when I go to WHM > MultiPHP Manager > and then see PHP handler I see suPHP is set on all. But still when I do phpinfo() i see fastcgi. Why & how do I set the PHP handler for web process ?